# 'to persuade' or 'persuade'

Tags: sentence-structure, verb-forms

I'm struggling to find an appropriate answer. In the sentence below, 'persuade' confuses me since it seems to me this word should take a -to before itself.

[Original BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20211209-how-to-talk-to-vaccine-hesitant-people):

> Researchers have been looking for ways to help governments **persuade** vaccine-hesitant people for some time.

Mine:

> Researchers have been looking for ways to help governments **to persuade** vaccine-hesitant people for some time.

Could somebody explain to me why this is the case here?

Answer (score 1):

'Help' may be followed by either a *to-infinitive* form of a verb, or a *bare-infinitive*. There is no difference in meaning.

> Could you help me **to look** for my car keys?

> Could you help me **look** for my car keys?

[Bare Infinitive (BBC English)](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv226.shtml#:%7E:text=Roger%20Woodham%20replies%3A,is%20no%20difference%20in%20meaning.&text=Help%20is%20a%20verb%20that,an%20object%20before%20the%20infinitive.)